# Rendering js partial with custom ajax request (instead of remote: true)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views

I don't want to use jQuery so I'm crafting my own ajax request with the following code:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", href, false);
xhReq.send(null);
var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
```

I'm letting Rails know that it is the JS format by adding `format: "js` to the `params`.

The `respond_to` block seems to work well, but I don't know how to get the code in the js-view to execute. I'm trying a simple `alert("hello");` but nothing happens.

Comment: `eval(serverResponse);` Or make a `script` element with the `href` instead of doing an XHR request, which may be better for performance.

Comment: Works great! (Put it as an answer and I will accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `eval(serverResponse);`

Or make a `script` element with the `href` instead of doing an XHR request, which may be better for performance.

```
var scrpt = document.createElement("script");
scrpt.src = href;
document.body.appendChild(scrpt);
```